# How 'exposed' do you store a password in a session?

Tags: security, session, hash, passwords, session-variables

I'm making a website using Python and Flask, and was wondering about something that is fairly important to me.

In the past, being the uneducated programmer I was, I always saved users' passwords unencrypted in the session, so that the username and password could be revalidated at request. Currently I'm making my first serious website, so I also want to do this a lot better.

I know that there are ways to sniff session variables, for instance by acquiring another person's session ID one way or the other. I want to know in what form it's best to store the password to hide it from people who have access to session data.

The options I have thought of so far:

- **Unencrypted**: Logically the worst option.
- **Hashed**: For instance, save `sha256(password)` to the session. This isn't a good option either, because crackers can use dictionary tables to retrieve the unencrypted password.
- **Salted & Hashed**: For instance, save `sha256(password+hash)` to the session. This is the most secure of the three options, but it will be a copy of the database entry and that doesn't seem like a good idea to me. A cracker could compare his own password to his own hash, and possibly figure out how salts and hashes are created for the entire database. I'm not sure if this is a valid concern, but I guess a knowledgeable user on Stackoverflow will be able to tell me. ;)
- **Salted & Hashed, with the database saving a recursively hashed string**: In essence this seems like a good option, but I've read that recursively hashing a password is always a bad idea.

So, which of these is recommended? Maybe a fifth one that I didn't think of? Note that this variable needs to be used to validate the user's credentials, so we can't just hash it with a different salt, or so.

Comment: Your question might be better suited for our sister site, http://security.stackexchange.com/, as it's more about general web application security practices than about a specific programming problem. However, FWIW, I've provided my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you need to store the user's password in the session *at all*?  I can't see any particular need for it, and it's just creating a potential security risk for no reason at all.

Instead, just store the username and, possibly, a flag stating that the user has been authenticated.  Of course, you should clear the flag (and/or just wipe the entire session data) when the user logs out, so that an attacker who somehow gets access to old session cookies can't resume the session after logout.

You may also want to store a "last access" timestamp in the session, so that you can let old stale sessions time out.  Or you could rely on your session framework's built-in session expiration behavior, but it may still be a good idea to have a backup mechanism fully under your app's direct control.

Ps. Obviously, *whatever* you do, make sure your session identifiers are generated using a cryptographically secure random number generator (e.g. [Crypto.Random.random](http://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/Crypto.Random.random-module.html)), and that they're long enough to be unguessable (at least 64 bits = 16 hex digits, although 128 bits is better).  If, for some reason, you *can't* do that, an alternative is to generate such a random token yourself, store it *both* in the session and in a cookie, and verify that the session and cookie tokens match before using any actual session data.

Comment: That sounds like a good answer. My question also concerns regular cookies though -- for some reasons it can be useful to save passwords for authentication purposes. For instance, if a user saves their credentials in cookies on one computer, then uses a different computer to **change** their password, the saved cookie should become invalid.

Comment: If you want to be able to invalidate _all_ sessions (or all but one session) for a given user, which I agree is a useful feature, one way to do that would be to store a "last logged in" timestamp in the session and a "last logged _out_" timestamp in the user database. Then just check on each request that the timestamp in the session is later than the one in the database. To force the user to log out, just update the timestamp in the database (and optionally the one in any sessions you want to keep).

Comment: Ps. If you need to store such values on the client side (e.g. in cookies), include a [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) with them to protect them from tampering. Don't forget to include the username in the MAC input.